# Topology that makes the finite set $X =\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ a regular space

Tags: general-topology

*Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applies* states

> Let X be a topological space. We say that $X$ is regular if
>   (i) One-point sets are closed in $X$;  (ii)  For every $a \in X$ and every closed set $B$ in $X$ that does not contain a, there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $a\in U$ and $B \subset V$

Clearly the discrete topology makes $X$ a regular space. Is there another type of topology that would also make $X$ a regular space?

Comment: In more traditional (and preferable) terminology this is the definition of a $T_3$ space; a *regular* space need only satisfy (ii), so that a $T_3$ space is a regular $T_1$ space. This makes that $T_n$ designations a genuine hierarchy, as they were intended to be. For some incomprehensible reason some people (like your source) reverse the terms.

Answer (score 5):

Not really: since all the $\{i\}$'s are closed, every finite union of them is also closed. Hence every finite subset of $X$ is closed. Since your space is finite, every subset of $X$ is closed. And you obtain the discrete topology.